# permission to open Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 Starter and at first had no problem with Windows Explorer.  And then one day it decided it couldn't open unless I gave it permission first. What comes up when I click on the Win Explorer icon is 'Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer?' This is one of its own programs. Why would it need permission and is there any way to get rid of this step?  I am in as owner/administrator with full control and there are no other users.

Comment: Does it have a valid digital signature?  If you are getting a UAC prompt and there is not a valid digital signature, then the Windows Explorer executable is likely to have been tampered with.  Windows Explorer should not require privilege elevation to use under normal circumstances.

Comment: Okay.  Where do I find that?  And is that something I can change if it turns out to not have one?   Thanks.

Comment: The digital signature should be visible if you click on the **Show details** drop-down and click on **Show information about this publisher's certificate**.  If this link is not available, or if the certificate is invalid, then Explorer is probably altered.  Try running a virus/spyware scan on the computer.